# How can I send a picture from android application via mms?

Tags: java, android, sendmessage

How can I send a picture from android application via MMS?
I found this code but I don't know how can I insert picture inside it
specially I want to let my application send the MMS. I do not want to send it via another application.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In this line `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));` the second argument must be Uri that indicates where your image store

Like this: `Uri myUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/1")`

And useful samples you can find here: [forum topic](http://androidforums.com/application-development/25988-send-image-action_send.html)

Comment: so when i put                                                                                                                           'Uri myUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/1")'   instead of                   'sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));' it will send it from my application?

Comment: you must put Uri with existing on your device image

Comment: or in your case, you should to prepare url with image

Comment: can you explain more? i do not get it

Comment: how can i do it,please can you tell me?

Comment: i will let user fill the form (image,name,age...)then the user click finish then i will send it to unique number, it is all inside my application, how can i do it?

Comment: my question is how can i send the image via MMS from my application?i hope i get replay from you

Comment: oh, you don't know how extract image from url? if yes then try `Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());`

Comment: sorry, i am just beginner who should doing complete application on 2 weeks :( thank you for your answer, so Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());   i should put it before 'Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");'

Comment: stop. this doesn't work `sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));`?)) you just need pass your  image url

Comment: so the code is:    `Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
    sendIntent.setType("image/png");     BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());`

Comment: note: the user will take the picture from Gallary, sorry i did not mention that earlier

Comment: can please please help me, i am really confuse! i need to complete code to send image -the user will choose it from gallery-via MMS on my application. I am sorry if i bothering you but i will appreciate it

Comment: from gallery that you create or users gallery?

Comment: from SD card the default gallery

Comment: so, take path of image [get file path from gallery image](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-file-path-of-gallery-image). be sure that your path looks like this `"content://media/external/images/1"` and send mms